# jQuery Library for pagination?

Tags: jquery, pagination

Actually I have searched but i am really bad at searching on web. My requirement is I hvae heard from somewhere that when you just create a table and use some jQuery library it will automatically do some things for you like

- Pagination
- Searching
- sorting

so I have search for this type of library do anyone knows about such libraries.

Need your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datatable is best one.

[**Check here**](https://www.datatables.net/)

DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

Features

```
Pagination, instant search and multi-column ordering
Supports almost any data source:
DOM, Javascript, Ajax and server-side processing
Easily theme-able: DataTables, jQuery UI, Bootstrap, Foundation
Wide variety of extensions inc. Editor, TableTools, FixedColumns and more
Extensive options and a beautiful, expressive API
Fully internationalisable
Professional quality: backed by a suite of 2900+ unit tests
Free open source software (MIT license)! Commercial support available.
Scrolling options for table viewport
Smart handling of column widths
State saving
Hidden columns
Dynamic creation of tables
Ajax auto loading of data
Custom DOM positioning
Single column filtering
Alternative pagination types
Non-destructive DOM interaction
Sorting column(s) highlighting
Advanced data source options
Commercial support available
Fully accessible for screenreaders / keyboard access
Sensible file size: 78K minified, 26K gzip'd
Extensive plug-in support
Sorting, type detection, API functions, pagination and filtering
Solid documentation and interface reference
130+ pre-built examples
```

Comment: I want to distribute the table in three columns will it work there too.?

Comment: Sure, its the most flexible plugin. I used it in every project almost.

Answer (score 2):

Here we have two examples of libraries for it , These libraries works Client side as well as Server side.

[Data Tables](https://www.datatables.net/)

and

[Jq grid](http://jqgrid.com/)

You can also compare them according to your needs .Here is the link to compare.
[Data Tables vs JqGrid](http://jqueryrock.com/2014/03/jqgrid-vs-datatable.html)

Comment: jQgrid is not allowing ajax pagination i guess, so better to go for Datatable. As you will never fetch entire `SELECT * .....` records , you will always be using offset , limit.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yes , i just gave him two examples and the difference so that he can choose according to his requirements .

Comment: Rohit, Its her **:)** !